# Does converting .eps files to .pdf (using epstopdf) for use with pdflatex have any negative consequences on image quality?

Tags: epstopdf

I like using .eps and have always used latex -> dvips -> pdf.   I'm happy to switch to pdflatex with epstopdf if here is no change in image quality.

Thank you.

Comment: Are the original images true vector files?

Comment: I'm not sure what the definition of "true vector file" is.  Typically my graphics are either:  .eps files printed directly to disk using Matlab, or .jpg (photos) converted to .eps using GIMP.  Would either of those be considered true vector graphics?

Comment: It may be that the EPS files from Matlab are true vector files, but conversions of JPG to EPS are not. You *will* lose quality if you convert the JPG-EPS files to PDF, as it includes another lossy conversion (however low the compression/high the quality is set; might not be noticeable). True vector file conversions should be lossless.

Comment: To prevent potential losses during conversion, just include your `jpg` files directly in pdflatex without converting them first. If the matlab files are vector images, there is no risk of such loss from epstopdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conversion from postscript to pdf is being done by the same software (ghostscript) whether to run epstopdf on the EPS file and then include that in the pdf stream being written by pdflatex, or whether you include the EPS into the Postscript stream written by dvips, and then use ps2pdf to convert the complete document to PDF, so in either case there are various options and flags you could set to make fine adjustments but there is no intrinsic difference in the conversion that happens to the EPS image.